# jQuery draggable - item go over the container on Chrome/Safari

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, safari, drag-and-drop

I have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ut2QL/19/) code :

## HTML

```
<div class="draggable_main_container">
    <div class="draggable_container">
        <div class="draggable">
            <div class="minus">
                label
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
.draggable_main_container
{
    width:134px;
    overflow:auto;
    position:relative;
    height:350px;
}

.draggable_container
{
    height:300px;
    position:relative;
    overflow:visible; 
    background-color:blue;  
}

.draggable
{           
    background-color:red;
    height:134px;
    width:134px;
    cursor:pointer;
    position:relative;
}

.draggable .minus
{
    position:absolute;
    left:50px;
    bottom:-20px;    
    width:32px;
    height:20px;  
    background-color:yellow;  
}
```

## jQuery

```
$(".draggable").draggable({
    axis: "y",
    containment: 'parent'
});
```

now, on Firefox there is no problems! On Chrome/Safari, it blocks when it get the bottom of the container.

Then, if I click and I scroll again to the bottom, the div move over the container. When it gets the main container height (350px) it also create the "scrolls" bars.

Well, to avoid the scroll bars is easy, just add `overflow:visible;` to `draggable_main_container`.

But what I need is really to block the draggable element when it get the parent bottom. How can I do it?

I think the problem is the position:absolute item attacched to the draggable item (the `.minus` one; in fact if I remove it, all works...)

Comment: I've had all kinds of cross-browser issues when trying to implement any of the built-in drag and drop stuff. I rolled my own using mouse or touch and made it work cross-browser, including mobile webkit. `draggable` is unreliable, imo.

Comment: this is not a solution! and Reinventing the wheel is not so good!

Comment: I didn't say it was a solution - that's why I put it in a comment rather than an answer. Re-inventing the wheel certainly applies if the wheel is half-round and half-square. Built-in drag and drop simply doesn't work well across browsers.

Comment: Yeah, but you can adjust it as well as possible... as every things in computer science I think. Also the main jQuery is not so perfect...

Comment: Yep - I used to have a drag drop on a grid that worked well - until chrome. Then fixed that - until mobile Safari. That's when I gave up and rolled my own. `draggable` especially gave me a problems when trying to implement it in a way that worked with mobile stuff - no dice. I tried to duplicate your problem in a jsfiddle, but it didn't drag at all (Safari on a Mac).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so I played around with your code a little and figured something out. And yes, its a fix.

So you are constraining your draggable by the draggable's parent .draggable_container. 
Now, in draggable, you have this minus thing that extends a bit from the bottom, which is fine until it sticks "outside" of .draggable_container". Except that it isn't sticking outside of it. The minus element is extending .draggable_container. Now when you click and then move draggable again, its parent element is temporarily bigger and thus it can scroll down further. Each time you drag it down a little more you're extending .draggable_container.

Now I don't know why this is only an issue when you click but that's what's happening.

The fix is to add 20px of padding to the bottom of .draggable_container. This stops the .minus element from extending .draggable_container.

You don't have the little effect of the "label" going outside the blue box but you can find another way to simulate this.